# Paths for storing Windows utility programs - pros and cons

Tags: windows, file-management

There are lots of utilities for Windows that just come as executables (no installers) so its up to you to decide where to save the files. A classic example is the [Sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/default) suite.

At the moment I usually stick them into **C:\Utils**

- The main con of this is that the
  directory is not indexed by default
  so you cannot launch the utils from the start menu without an extra step.
- A minor con is it doesn't 'feel' very legit (i.e. I think according to Windows standards you are not meant to store stuff outside of Users or Program Files these days).

I am wondering what the pros and cons of using other paths are, and hence are there better options than C:\Utils that I haven't thought of.

Answer (score 3):

I've been doing this for several years, adding the location to `%PATH%` and syncing the directory across all my machines using Windows Live Mesh.  I also include a load of other stuff, including scripts, other shells, Cygwin, portable Python and portable apps from PortableApps.com.

The location does get indexed once it is added to your `%PATH%`, in my experience (at least the contents appear in the start menu search box).

If you do not like putting them on the root of `C:`, you could put them in `Public` and then make a symbolic link pointing to then from the root of `C:`, using `MKLINK`.

To add the directory to `%PATH%` permanently, type:

```
setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\Utils"
```

To make a symbolic link pointing to `Public` from the root of `C:`, type:

```
mklink /d "C:\Utils" "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Utils"
```

Comment: PS. I do not put my Utils directory within %PROGRAMFILES% as Windows Live Mesh refuses to sync files in there.

Answer (score 1):

If a utility doesn't balk at having a space in its path, I put them in `C:\Program Files\Utils`. Otherwise, I use `C:\Utils`.

If a utility is one that is run from the command line, I use `C:\Utils` and add that directory to my `PATH` so I don't have to have a space in it (although Windows doesn't care).

If a group of programs have something common, such as the Sysinternals suite, I will usually dedicate a directory exclusively to them.

My reasons are mainly organizational.

- How do I use them?
- What is their purpose?
- Do I use them together?
- etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remain organised and to put such applications in an appropriate place, avoid `Program Files` and `Program Files (x86)` as these are for 64-bit and 32-bit (respectively) applications installed through the operating system and available to all users. I would keep manually installed applications in your own user profile folder (`%USERPROFILE%`), in particular the `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Programs` folder. This is where per-user applications are also installed, but it would isolate your manually installed applications to your own user profile folder as well as keeping them alongside of other programs.